# Issue in sending mail using AWS SESClient yii2 with PDF attachment

Tags: php, yii2, amazon-ses, mpdf

We are trying to send the email to the multiple users with PDF attachment. The attached PDF is generated via kartik\mpdf\Pdf.

Steps we have followed

1. Fetch users and message content from the DB
2. For all available users generate Email object and also generate PDF and send that mail with attached pdf.
3. To send the email we are using amazon SES.

## In config file pdf component is set

```
'pdf' => [
    'class' => Pdf::classname(),
    'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
    'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
    'destination' => Pdf::DEST_STRING,
]
```

===========================

## Code in  PHP file to send email

```
use Aws\Ses\SesClient;

//Fetch all records whose mail_send is 0 and in_queue is 0
$email_model = new MailQueue();
$mail_queue_data = // select query to get Email IDs, email content etc from mail queue table;

foreach($mail_queue_data as $result) 
{
    try {
        // Create SES client Instance
        $gaws_ses_client = SesClient::factory(array(
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => 'us-east-1',
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => 'YOUR_KEY',
                'secret' => 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY',
            ]
        ));

        // Set SES linked user email
        $my_from_address = 'this_is_test@demo.com';

        $my_string_to_addresses = $result['to_email'];
        $my_array_to_adresses = [$my_string_to_addresses];

        $my_subject = isset($result['subject']) ? $result['subject'] : '';
        $my_html_body = isset($result['email_html']) ? $result['email_html'] : '';

        // Set mail message
        $my_message = "";
        $my_message .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $my_message .= "To: ".$my_string_to_addresses."\n"; 
        $my_message .= "From:".$my_from_address."\n";   
        $my_message .= "Subject:".$my_subject."\n";

        $my_separator = md5(time());
        $my_separator_multipart = md5($my_subject . time());

        // Set headers
        $my_message .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$my_separator_multipart."\"\n";
        $my_message .= "\n--".$my_separator_multipart."\n";
        $my_message .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"".$my_separator."\"\n";
        $my_message .= "\n--".$my_separator."\n";
        $my_message .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n";
        $my_message .= "\n".$my_html_body."\n";
        $my_message .= "\n--".$my_separator."--\n";

        $content = $my_html_body;
        $pdf = Yii::$app->pdf;
        $pdf->cssFile = '@backend/web/css/externalcss_file_name.css';
        $pdf->content = $content;
        $raw_data = $pdf->render();

        $my_file_name = 'attachment.pdf';

        $my_data_attached_file = chunk_split(base64_encode($raw_data));

        $file_info = new \finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
        $my_file_mime_type = $file_info->buffer($raw_data);

        $my_message .= "--".$my_separator_multipart."\n";
        $my_message .= "Content-Type: ".$my_file_mime_type."; name=\"".$my_file_name."\"\n";
        $my_message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$my_file_name."\"\n";
        $my_message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n";
        $my_message .= $my_data_attached_file."\n";
        $my_message .= "--".$my_separator_multipart."--";

        $my_array_ses = [
            'Source'       => $my_from_address,
            'Destinations' => $my_array_to_adresses,
            'RawMessage'   => [
                'Data' => $my_message
            ]
        ];

        $my_api_result = $gaws_ses_client->sendRawEmail($my_array_ses);

        //view sample output
        echo "\n<BR>SES Result:<BR>\n";
        echo "Message ID : ".$my_api_result['MessageId']."<BR>\n";
        print_r($my_api_result);
        echo "<BR>\n";

    } catch (Exception $my_obj_error) {
        //An error happened and the email did not get sent
        $my_error_info = $my_obj_error->getMessage();

        echo "\n<BR>*** SES ERROR:<BR>\n";
        print_r($my_error_info);
        echo "<BR>\n";      

        $myfile = fopen("ses_send_error.txt", "w");
        fwrite($myfile, $my_error_info);
        fclose($myfile);

    }
}
```

4. Now, if we are trying to send only one email then its working fine. But if we are sending email to the mutiple users then we are getting below error:

> PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
>
> Undefined index: data

That exception generates when PDF contains images. If we generate PDF without images, it works properly. So how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: do you need to pass array to `Destinations`, looks like you are passing a string

Comment: whats the format of `my_string_to_addresses `. if its comma separated, you may have to do something like `explode(", ","a@b.com, b@c.com")`

Comment: The variable `result['to_email']` is in loop and will contain always string like "demo@gmail.com". And to pass this value in `my_string_to_addresses` for `Destinations`, I have tried with `explode(", ",$result['to_email'])`. But Still getting same error.

Actually I think issue is with attachment PDF. If generated PDF contains the image i.e. `<tr><img src="YOUR_IMG_URL" /> </tr>` error appears.

Comment: What urls are you using for the images? I guess it might have trouble resolving relative urls if you are using them. You should try referncing images with absolute urls including the protocol (http://...).

Comment: The images are rendered from S3 bucket. Also the server on which the PDF is generated and the images path both having https:// .

I always got images for the first email iteration. The error/problem starts with the 2nd or 3rd iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In order to troubleshoot this, I would suggest to hardcode the to email addresses as below. Make sure to add the real email addresses. Once you get it working, then you can format the `my_string_to_addresses` to this format.

```
$my_array_to_adresses = ['email1@domain.com', 'email2@domain.com'];
```

Comment: Just tried with 
`$my_array_to_adresses = ['mypersonal_1@gmail.com', 'mypersonal_2@gmail.com', 'other_real_1@gmail.com', other_real_2@gmail.com];`

But same issue and same error. (as was in original issue).

Comment: but if you do $my_array_to_adresses = ['mypersonal_1@gmail.com'];  it works?

Comment: The problem is in pdf generation not in sending mails so there is no point in trying to debug it this way.

Comment: To isolate the problem to SES, you can try removing the attachment

Comment: If I remove PDF attachment related stuff, It works properly. @ArunmainthanKamalanathan. Yes agreed @ Michal Hynčica

Specially when the PDF is generated with Images. Note that the PDF generation is in loop. So if there are 5 entries in mail_queue table, then there are 5 loop iterations for individual PDF generation. All users may have different PDF data.